# How to draw a heart in qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, draw

I need to draw an heart on qt creator, but i have a problem when I use drawArc. I know I'm using it the wrong way, but i don't know what to do. A little help please? that's the code to draw heart in c++.

```
HeartDrawableStrategy::draw(QPainter &painter, QRect &rect, double xRatio, double yRatio, QPoint &pos, int size,)
{
    //Define the heart points
    int newPointX = pos.x();
    int newPointY = pos.y()+size/4;
    QPoint leftPoint = QPoint(newPointX*xRatio, newPointY*yRatio);

    newPointX = pos.x()+size/2;
    newPointY = pos.y() + size;
    QPoint bottomCenterPoint = QPoint(newPointX*xRatio, newPointY*yRatio);

    newPointX = pos.x() + size;
    newPointY = pos.y() + size/4;
    QPoint rightPoint = QPoint(newPointX*xRatio, newPointY*yRatio);

    newPointX = pos.x() + size/2;
    newPointY = pos.y() + size/4;
    QPoint middlePoint = QPoint(newPointX*xRatio, newPointY*yRatio);

    newPointX = pos.x() + size/4;
    newPointY = pos.y();
    QPoint topLeftPoint = QPoint(newPointX*xRatio, newPointY*yRatio);

    newPointX = pos.x() + (size*3/4);
    newPointY = pos.y();
    QPoint topRightPoint = QPoint(newPointX*xRatio, newPointY*yRatio);

    //Draw the heart
    QLine line = QLine(leftPoint, bottomCenterPoint);
    painter.drawLine(line);

    line = QLine(bottomCenterPoint, rightPoint);
    painter.drawLine(line);

    line = QLine(leftPoint, middlePoint);
    painter.drawArc(line);

    line = QLine(middlePoint, rightPoint);
    painter.drawArc(line);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently create a QLine, and you try to create a arc with it. This can not work.

According to the [QT Doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawArc)
You need a start point in X, a start point in Y, a width, a height, a start angle and a span angle.
Like that :

```
painter.drawArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, spanAngle);
```

X and Y is the top-left corner and the startAngle and spanAngle must be specified in 1/16th of a degree, i.e. a full circle equals 5760 (16 * 360). Positive values for the angles mean counter-clockwise while negative values mean the clockwise direction. Zero degrees is at the 3 o'clock position.

The code bellow :

```
painter.drawArc(10, 20, 80, 60, (30 * 16), (120 * 16);
```

Will drew this :

[image: drawArc]